# Why I installed Networkx and cannot import or even find graphviz_layout?

Tags: python, import, networkx

I installed networkx by using pip, however I cannot use the example given because I cannot import graphviz_layout. Then I download networkx and unzip it by myself. Still I cannot find graphviz_layout in the folder. There is just layout.py. Does anybody knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function for graphviz_layout() is in the nx_agraph.py file:
http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_agraph.html#graphviz_layout

In order to use it in NetworkX you need to also install PyGraphviz https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygraphviz

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I use Windows which may cause the problem. I installed graphviz and then I modified the library_path and include_path in the setup.py. However I still cannot install pygraphviz, the error is like `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it helps a lot. Though I cannot make it work under Windows, but I can make it work in Linux now. So, thank you!

Comment: There are some other SO questions and answers about installing PyGraphviz with Windows.  It is possible but not that easy I guess.